# How to create pull request on a cloned repo?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

**Context**

There is a github repo. The repo owner asked me to commit some changes. However I do not have write permission, or even fork permission on that particular repo. The owner then asked me:

*"You should be able to clone the repo and send me a pull request when you are done"*

I am familiar the github fork concept. Now this is not an option. I am also familiar how to create a local clone.

**Question**

So I've created a local clone, and added some changes. I can commit it locally.
What's next? How can I create a pull req and "send it" to a particular user?

(I am using Visual Studio 2015 as git client, but explanations using git command line or SourceTree also welcome.

Comment: "Now this is not an option" But this is the correct way to do this with github.Fork the project to your own repository, clone *that* push your changes to that, and then make a pull request. Why is it not an option?

Comment: OK thanks. Just wondering "pull request" is a GitHub specific thing, or more generic. In case it is not GitHub specific then how it could be accomplished against a pure git server?

Answer (score 1):

You have to fork the repo first before being able to create a pull request on GitHub. If it is a public repo I don't think forking can be prevented even.

Other than that you can at most let Git create a patch with `git format-patch` and send it via mail to the repo owner or tell him to pull from your machine if your machine is accessible by his machine.